# Is there a way to configure postgresql to send records to a listener port

Tags: postgresql, logging, port, portforwarding

I am having a situation where I need to send new record in a specific table, to a tcp port on server.

Is there a chance to configure this in postgresql.conf file. I am also open to any suggestion of how to send data to the port from a trigger function.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger in PL/Python that can do about anything with the new row, but that doesn't sound like a good idea. For example, it would mean that the `INSERT` would fail if the trigger function encounters an error, and it would make the inserting transaction last unduly long.

I think what you want is [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) with a plugin like [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. PL/Python cannot be used in my use case.I can only use plpgsql

Comment: Is there a way to write data to a seperate log file from plpgsql procedures

Comment: You can use `pg_write_file` from [adminpack](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/adminpack.html). Why all these strange requirements and limitations?

Comment: Can I use COPY to write NEW (of datatype record, from trigger function)  values to a file?

Comment: I need to make changes in a developed product. Any new third party source will take some time to be approved.

Comment: I don't know about `COPY`. Maybe with transition tables. Adminpack is not a third-party source, it is part of the PostgreSQL core distribution.